# recurrence relation dependent inversly on n

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

I recently learnt to find out nth number fibonacci series by matrix exponentiation. 
but i am stuck on two relations :

```
1) F(n) = F(n−1) + n            
2) F(n) = F(n−1) + 1/n
```

Is there any efficient way to solve these in
    O(logn)
time like we have matrix expo. for fibonacci series ?

Comment: Cross Posted: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485896/recurrence-relation-dependent-inversly-on-n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is obviously equal to:

```
F(n) = F(0) + n*(n+1)/2
```

and can be computed in O(1) time.  For the second, look [here](http://members.bex.net/jtcullen515/Math5.htm).

---

Supposing that you want to compute the first one with matrix exponentiation, in the same way that you did with the Fibonacci series, here's the matrix you should use:

```
    | 1 1 0 |
A = | 0 1 1 |
    | 0 0 1 |
```

The choice of matrix is obvious if you think of the following equation:

```
| F(n+1) |   | 1 1 0 |   | F(n) |
|  n+1   | = | 0 1 1 | * |  n   |
|   1    |   | 0 0 1 |   |  1   |
```

Of course, the starting vector has to be: `(F(0), 0, 1)`.

For the second series this is not so easy, as you would want to gradually compute the value `1/n`, which cannot be computed linearly in this way.  I guess it cannot be done but I won't try to prove it.

Comment: The link tells you that the second has a solution of `F(0)+H_n`, where `H_n` is the nth harmonic number.  But that doesn't help too much, since the nth harmonic number is precisely the sum that we're looking at.  I don't think there is a useful formula.

Comment: as you pointed out to the first recurrence , i want to know whether it can be solved by matrix exponentiation also and if not what "types" of recurrence relations can be solved by it.

Comment: OK, let's say you want to try as an exercise to compute them in the same way that you did the Fibonacci...  I'll update my answer in a short while.

Comment: The link states Psi(n)=log(Gamma(n)), so F(n) = log(n!)-log(1), which is incorrect.

You could approximate it though without looping through large values of n, by numerically evaluating the integral $\int_0^1\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}\,dx$ to arbitrary degree of precision.

Answer (score 0):

The first one can be calculated in `O(1)` just because this is an arithmetic progression and the sum is `n*(n-1)/2`.

The second one is a [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) and can not be calculated efficiently, but you can approximate it in `O(1)` with:

[image]

where the first one is a [0.57721566490153286060](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) and the second is approximately `1/(2k)`